# Consulta en PHP a tabla

Tags: php, mysql

| driver_id | delivery_date | delivery_fee | driver_tip | paymethod | a_devolver |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 12877 | 2022-11-09 | 1800 | 1335 | Tarjeta | 0 |
| 2071 | 2022-11-09 | 4190 | 885 | Tarjeta | 0 |
| 14581 | 2022-11-09 | 1800 | 0 | Efectivo | 8500 |
| 12216 | 2022-11-09 | 4600 | 0 | Tarjeta | 0 |
| 12877 | 2022-11-09 | 5600 | 2190 | Efectivo | 13550 |
| 12216 | 2022-11-09 | 1800 | 0 | Tarjeta | 0 |
| 2071 | 2022-11-09 | 1800 | 0 | Efectivo | 6550 |
| 2071 | 2022-11-09 | 2100 | 0 | Tarjeta | 0 |
| 12877 | 2022-11-09 | 1800 | 0 | Efectivo | 9100 |
| 2071 | 2022-11-09 | 2400 | 1434 | Tarjeta | 0 |

Hola a todos. Tengo la siguiente tabla y necesito poder entregar un resumen de lo que debe devolver cada driver al empleador o en su defecto este depositarle, el cálculo se obtiene de restar a lo que me debe devolver (a_devolver) los valores del delivery_fee y driver_tip solo de los paymethod que son con Tarjeta.

```
$sqlSelect = "SELECT v.driver_id, q.nombre_quicker, q.apellido_quicker, SUM(-delivery_fee-driver_tip) as Depositar FROM ventas as v INNER JOIN quickers as q ON q.driver_id = v.driver_id WHERE paymethod = 'Tarjeta' GROUP BY driver_id UNION SELECT v.driver_id, q.nombre_quicker, q.apellido_quicker, SUM(a_devolver) as Depositar2 FROM ventas as v INNER JOIN quickers as q ON q.driver_id = v.driver_id WHERE paymethod = 'Efectivo' GROUP BY driver_id";
```

.

Intente con esta consulta pero no me sirvió.

Lo que necesito que salga es:

| driver_id | delivery_date | Depostarme |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 12877 | 2022-11-09 | 19515 |
| 2071 | 2022-11-09 | -4459 |
| 14581 | 2022-11-09 | 8500 |
| 12216 | 2022-11-09 | -6400 |

Comment: Crea una tabla con unos pocos ejemplos de cada tipo y facilítanos el resultado que te gustaría obtener para esos datos de muestra. Aporta todo en SQL con phpmyadmin, exportar.

Comment: Tu modelo de datos está mal diseñado. Cuando la venta sea con tarjeta vas a tener en blanco la columna `a_devolver`, será, en esos casos, una columna muerta, que está ahí ocupando espacio. Deberías considerar seriamente una normalización de ese modelo de datos, trasladando a otra tabla los casos de pago en efectivo, donde tengas el valor a devolver.

Comment: Estimado @A.Cedano el problema es que el sistema que lleva los registro y dinámica del negocio exporta así el archivo csv, soy bastante principiante en PHP y MySQL, estoy intentando ayudar a mi hermano en su emprendimiento, la idea es poder subir ese mismo archivo y que el sistema lo pudiese procesar. Si me expresé mal en mi consulta mil disculpas, lo que al fin de cuentas necesito es saber como se hace para que por cada driver_id me pueda mostrar el valor de la variable a_devolver  - (delivery_fee+driver_tip) solo de los pagos en tarjeta, gracias por la ayuda y comprensión

Comment: Tienes que agregar un filtro en la consulta para que tome en cuenta solamente los pagos en efectivo, algo así más o menos: `... WHERE v. paymethod='Tarjeta'`

Comment: Estimado al colocar ese filtro me deja afuera el pago con efectivo que es donde esta el valor que me deben devolver.

Comment: Estimado @DavidJP  Si me expresé mal en mi consulta mil disculpas, lo que sucede es que un driver_id puede hacer ventas por tarjeta o por efectivo en las 2 va a tener un delivery_fee y puede o no tener driver_tip, lo que necesito saber es como se hace para que por cada driver_id me pueda mostrar el valor de la variable a_devolver (que puede ser 0 o x) - (delivery_fee+driver_tip) solo de los pagos en tarjeta, ya que al pagar en efectivo el delivery_feey el driver_tip se lo deja en el acto para él, gracias por la ayuda y comprensión.

Comment: No son necesarias tantas explicaciones, añádelas a la pregunta si crees que pueden llegar a ser necesarias para aclarar alguna excepción. Con el ejemplo sencillo que te pido, suele ser más que suficiente para poder responderte. Por favor, apórtalo.

Comment: Parecería que con un `CASE WHEN` se podría resolver el problema, pero el planteamiento no es muy claro. Por favor pulsa en [edit] y explica con la mayor simplicidad posible el contexto y lo que quieres obtener, poniendo un ejemplo concreto basado en datos. Si aportaras un fiddle con un pequeño set de datos, agilizaría una respuesta satisfactoria.

Comment: No necesitas hacer `UNION`: `sum( a_devolver -if( paymethod = 'Tarjeta', delivery_fee+driver_tip, 0) ) Depostarme`.

Comment: MUCHAS GRACIAS @Sal!!!! eso era justamente lo que necesitaba te pasaste por la ayuda